# Interfaces, structs and boxing is this code doing what I think?

Tags: c#, struct, interface, boxing

I was reading through this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15209464/1073672
Here is the code, copied for completeness and slightly simplified.

```
using System;

namespace Test
{
    interface IFoo
    {
        int Foobar{get;set;}
    }
    struct Foo : IFoo 
    {
        public int Foobar{ get; set; }
    }

    class Bar
    {
        // These two lines. I can not understand how they will work.
        Foo tmp;
        public IFoo Biz{ get { return tmp; } set { tmp = (Foo) value; } }

        public Bar()
        {
            Biz = new Foo(){Foobar=0};
        }
    }


    class MainClass
    {
        // This is not really important.
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            var mybar = new Bar();
        }
    }
}
```

How do construction of `Bar` and assignment to `Biz` work?
My take:

1. In Bar constructor create a struct of type `Foo()` and set its Foobar = 0;
2. Cast to type of `IFoo` by using boxing (?) (since `Biz` has type `IFoo`)
3. Unbox the reference type `IFoo` to value type struct `(Foo)` and assign to tmp.

So is this description correct? This is really un/boxing even if we don't make use of the object class?

Comment: If you compile with optimizations and decompile it with ildasm, do you see boxing IL instructions?

Comment: @cubrr thanks, such an obvious idea, but I did not think of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your description is correct. Casting a `struct` to an interface causes boxing.

An interesting side effect is that assigning to `Bar.Biz.Foobar` will not cause any changes:

```
var mybar = new Bar();
mybar.Biz.Foobar = 2;
int fooBar = mybar.Biz.Foobar; // still 0
```

Mutable `struct`s are evil.