# Pass constructor arguments when deserializing into a List(Of T)

Tags: .net, vb.net, json.net, office-interop

I need to serialize and deserialize a `List(of T)` via JSON.Net, where `T` is an object which contains a reference which cannot be serialized. Here is a simplified version:

```
Class MyObject

    Private ReadOnly _Parent As Word.Document

    Property Foo As String
    Property Bar As String

    Sub New(Parent As Word.Document, Foo As String, Bar As String)
        Me.New(Parent)
        Me.Foo = Foo
        Me.Bar = Bar
    End Sub

    Sub New(Parent As Word.Document)
        _Parent = Parent
    End Sub

    <JsonConstructor>
    Private Sub New()
    End Sub

    Function GetFile() As System.IO.FileInfo
        Return New FileInfo(_Parent.FullName)
    End Function

End Class
```

For the story, I store the JSON string (serialized list) inside a Word document variable. When I open the document, I take the string, deserialize it, and then I would like to be able to set the `_Parent` field to refer to the same document.
The difficulty is not in knowing what `_Parent` should reference to, but to set the reference. Note I want to keep it `Private`, however it could be read/write if necessary.

Is there a way to tell JSON.Net to use the `New(Parent As Word.Document)` constructor, and to pass this `Parent` argument via `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of T)`?
Or at least to tell JSON.Net I want to run a specific Sub before/after deserializing?

An easy bypass is be to have the constructor below, but I dot not like it as it may get messed up if several documents are opened at the same time.

```
<JsonConstructor>
Private Sub New()
    _Parent = ThisWordApp.ActiveDocument
End Sub
```

I'm fine with responses in C#.

Comment: `Word.Document` is a reference which is created by the Word COM model, when a document is open. Not sure what you mean by "modify", but for a given document, if I close and reopen it, the `Word.Document` reference would be different. Yes, a `Collection(Of T)` is fine.

Comment: The idea is I have a document I work on, I do some things which create some MyObjects. I save the document and close it (the list/collection of these objects is serialized into the document). On another day I open the document and the list/collection of MyObjects is available.

Comment: Following the article you mentioned, looks like I could use  the `<OnDeserialized>` attribute, but still I would be unable to pass the `Word.Document` object as an argument of the Sub to run `OnDeserialized`. https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationCallbacks.htm

Comment: Word.Document cannot be modified. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word.document

Comment: You might consider the approach from [Pass additional data to JsonConverter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53196799/3744182).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could adopt the second approach from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53196799/3744182) to *[Pass additional data to JsonConverter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53193503/3744182)* and create a [`CustomCreationConverter(Of MyObject)`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeCustomCreationConverter.htm) that allocates an instance of `MyObject` using a `Word.Document` passed into the converter itself.

First, define the following converter:

```
Class MyObjectConverter
    Inherits CustomCreationConverter(Of MyObject)

    Private ReadOnly _Parent As Word.Document           

    Sub New(Parent As Word.Document)
        If Parent Is Nothing Then
            Throw New ArgumentNullException("Parent")
        End If
        _Parent = Parent
    End Sub

    Overrides Function Create(objectType as Type) As MyObject
        Return New MyObject(_Parent)
    End Function
End Class
```

Then you can use it as follows:

```
Dim settings = New JsonSerializerSettings() With { .Converters = { new MyObjectConverter(document) } }
Dim list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of MyObject))(jsonString, settings)
```

Notes:

- This solution has the added advantage that you no longer need the `<JsonConstructor> Private Sub New()` constructor for `MyObject` and can completely remove it.
- This converter would never be applied at compile time using [`JsonConverterAttribute`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverterAttribute.htm), it should only be constructed in runtime given a known `Word.Document` (the `document` variable in the code sample above).

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/nAFpMH).

Comment: That looks good!  Unable to test it right now but I think that is what I needed. I really like the added advantage that there is no need  to include JSON Attributes in the serializable class.

Comment: @Jimi - related question asked and answered here: [How can I deserialize instances of a type that has read-only back-references to some container type also being deserialized?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56316631/3744182).  An on-point question title should make it more easily searchable.