# How can I deserialize instances of a type that has read-only back-references to some container type also being deserialized?

Tags: c#, json, vb.net, json.net

Let's say I have two types, a `Document` and a `Child`.  The `Child` is nested fairly deeply within the `Document`, and contains a back-reference to the parent that must needs be passed into its constructor.  How can I deserialize such an object graph with Json.NET and pass the parent into the child's constructor?

Here's a concrete example, inspired by *[Pass constructor arguments when deserializing into a List(Of T)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56308478/3744182)* by [Ama](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10794555/ama):

```vb
Class Document
    Public Property MyObjects as List(Of Child) = new List(Of Child)()
End Class

Class Child
    Private ReadOnly _Parent As Document

    Sub New(Parent As Document)
        _Parent = Parent
    End Sub

    Property Foo As String
    Property Bar As String

    Function GetParent() As Document
        Return _Parent
    End Function
End Class
```

With the corresponding JSON:

```
{
  "MyObjects": [
    {
      "Foo": "foo",
      "Bar": "bar"
    }
  ]
}
```

Notes:

- The parent reference in `Child` is read-only and must be passed into the constructor.
- I cannot modify the class definitions for `Document` and `Child`.
- `Document` and `Child` are more complicated that shown here, so loading into a `JToken` hierarchy then constructing manually is not preferred.

How can I deserialize JSON to such a data model, constructing the list of children with the parent properly initialized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the definitions for `Document` and `Child` cannot be modified, one way to do this would be with a [custom contract resolver](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/contractresolver.htm#CustomIContractResolverExamples) that returns contracts that track the current document being deserialized in some [`ThreadLocal(Of Stack(Of Document))`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadlocal-1) stack, and allocate instances of `MyObject` using the topmost document.

The following contract resolver does the job:

```vb
Public Class DocumentContractResolver
    Inherits DefaultContractResolver

    Private ActiveDocuments As ThreadLocal(Of Stack(Of Document)) = New ThreadLocal(Of Stack(Of Document))(Function() New Stack(Of Document))

    Protected Overrides Function CreateContract(ByVal objectType As Type) As JsonContract
        Dim contract = MyBase.CreateContract(objectType)
        Me.CustomizeDocumentContract(contract)
        Me.CustomizeMyObjectContract(contract)
        Return contract
    End Function

    Private Sub CustomizeDocumentContract(ByVal contract As JsonContract)
        If GetType(Document).IsAssignableFrom(contract.UnderlyingType) Then
            contract.OnDeserializingCallbacks.Add(Sub(o, c) ActiveDocuments.Value.Push(CType(o, Document)))
            contract.OnDeserializedCallbacks.Add(Sub(o, c) ActiveDocuments.Value.Pop())
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub CustomizeMyObjectContract(ByVal contract As JsonContract)
        If (GetType(Child) = contract.UnderlyingType) Then
            contract.DefaultCreator = Function() New Child(ActiveDocuments.Value.Peek())
            contract.DefaultCreatorNonPublic = false
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

And then use it like:

```vb
Dim contractResolver = New DocumentContractResolver() ' Cache this statically somewhere
Dim settings = New JsonSerializerSettings() With { .ContractResolver = contractResolver }

Dim doc2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Document)(jsonString, settings)
```

And in c#:

```cs
public class DocumentContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    ThreadLocal<Stack<Document>> ActiveDocuments = new ThreadLocal<Stack<Document>>(() => new Stack<Document>());

    protected override JsonContract CreateContract(Type objectType)
    {
        var contract = base.CreateContract(objectType);
        CustomizeDocumentContract(contract);
        CustomizeMyObjectContract(contract);
        return contract;
    }

    void CustomizeDocumentContract(JsonContract contract)
    {
        if (typeof(Document).IsAssignableFrom(contract.UnderlyingType))
        {
            contract.OnDeserializingCallbacks.Add((o, c) => ActiveDocuments.Value.Push((Document)o));
            contract.OnDeserializedCallbacks.Add((o, c) => ActiveDocuments.Value.Pop());
        }
    }

    void CustomizeMyObjectContract(JsonContract contract)
    {
        if (typeof(Child) == contract.UnderlyingType)
        {
            contract.DefaultCreator = () => new Child(ActiveDocuments.Value.Peek());
            contract.DefaultCreatorNonPublic = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Notes:

- If an exception occurs during deserialization the `ActiveDocuments` might not get cleared properly.  You might want to add a [serialization error handler](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationErrorHandling.htm) to do that.
- As explained in [Newtonsoft's performance tips](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Performance.htm#ReuseContractResolver),

  > To avoid the overhead of recreating contracts every time you use JsonSerializer you should create the contract resolver once and reuse it.
- [`ThreadLocal<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadlocal-1) is disposable, so if you *don't* plan to cache your `WordContractResolver` you should probably make it disposable also, and dispose of the threadlocal in the dispose method.

Demo fiddles [here (vb.net)](https://dotnetfiddle.net/N2tHPz) and [here (c#)](https://dotnetfiddle.net/tLSTsC).