# "..." cannot implement an interface member because it is not public

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext

```
public interface IDatabaseContext : IDisposable {

    IDbSet<MyEntity1> Entities1 { get; set; }

}

public class MyDbContext : DbContext, IDatabaseContext {

    IDbSet<MyEntity1> Entities1 { get; set; }

}
```

Can't compile because of the error described in here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-Us/library/bb384253(v=vs.90).aspx

However, this makes no sence since the interface obviously IS public. What could be the error here?

Comment: It makes perfect sense, when you interpret "it" as referring to the subject of the sentence: the intended implementation member, not the interface member. (In other words, MyDbContext.Entities1... which is private, currently.)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

> However, this makes no sence since the interface obviously IS public. What could be the error here?

No, it isn't. Members on classes are `private` by default. This `Entities1` is private:

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext, IDatabaseContext {    
    IDbSet<MyEntity1> Entities1 { get; set; }    
}
```

Note that this is different to `interface`s, where everything is `public` and access modifiers **do not make sense**. So: either make the member `public`:

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext, IDatabaseContext {    
    public IDbSet<MyEntity1> Entities1 { get; set; }    
}
```

or do an explicit interface implementation:

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext, IDatabaseContext {    
    IDbSet<MyEntity1> IDatabaseContext.Entities1 { get; set; }    
}
```

Comment: Dear god. How did I not see that? Well, seems like I eternalized myself forever in the SO hall of shame. :/

Comment: @Acrotygma rest assured: when somebody else spots something, it is only through hard-won battle experience of having made the same mistake themselves, probably several times

Comment: The reason to use `explicit interface implementation` is to control visibility for some methods otherwise `public` access modifier is used. [Here's](https://www.devcurry.com/2015/03/c-cannot-implement-interface-member.html) a good article about it too.

Answer (score 8):

When implementing an interface member in the class, **it should be `public`**

See: [Interfaces (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173156.aspx)

> To implement an interface member, the corresponding member of the
>   implementing class **must be public,** non-static, and have the same
>   name and signature as the interface member.

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext, IDatabaseContext {

    public IDbSet<MyEntity1> Entities1 { get; set; }
}
```

Or as @Marc Gravell said in comment you can do [Explicit interface implemenation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173157.aspx), More could be found at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1392281/961113)

Comment: Well, it doesn't *have* to be public - it could be an explicit interface implementation too...

Comment: @MarcGravell, yes, I should  add that to the answer

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue only to discover that I forgot to make the method of the interface public. Make sure all the methods of the interface are public too.

Answer (score 0):

To simplify the answer/logic -

Your problem is that interfaces **ARE MEANT to be public in the inheriting class** (this is why it is called an interface).

Therefore you must mark the implementation in the derived class as public (in MyDbContext).

Answer (score -1):

Interface member can be implemeted as Protected too.
If you dont want we can leave it as abstract incase of Abstract classes.

Comment: No, they can't; a `protected` member does not implicitly implement an interface, and an *explicit* interface implementation is not `protected`.